# Jquery, know width and height of a div with scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want have width and height of a full div with scroll using JQuery, but i can only have size of visible content and not size of visible + hidden content of scroll bar.

Anyone knows anyway to have this values (width and height)?

```
<div id="area" class="divLeftCem area">
    <div id="panelArea" class="areaBackground"
        style="width: 1004px; height: 613px; background: #FFFFFF url('Images/background.png') repeat;">
    </div>
</div>

.area
{
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 1004px;
    height: 613px;
    border: 1px solid #AFAFAF;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 145px;
}
```

PS: Sorry about bad english.

Comment: I think jQuery gives you the actual size of the div. Could you put some code examples?

Comment: Exact, only give me the visible size of the div.

Comment: I mean, it should give you the size of the complete div. Please, edit your question and add some code examples

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Get the element's `.scrollHeight`:

```
$(".el").get(0).scrollHeight;
```

​
It goes without saying you could use `.scrollWidth` for the x-axis as well.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spN6n/

Comment: Still don't work. Don't give me the scroll page width or something usable.

Comment: @Quaquil Check the link in my answer. This solution appears to work just fine.

Comment: You are right. This don't work with me because postback of .net, ty